# In how many ways can the webpages be arranged if pages of the same type must be adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

"Thomas has $16$ webpages open in his browser and he wants to arrange them. There are $4$ Wikipedia pages, 3 university websites, 2 google searches, 4 Amazon pages, and 3 eBay pages. How many ways can he arrange all 16 webpages in his browser if pages of the same type must be adjacent, and the Amazon group must be adjacent to the eBay group (in either order)?"

I did $4!\cdot 3! \cdot 2! \cdot 4!\cdot 3! \cdot 4!$ which equals 995,328. The 4! at the end is me treating Amazon and eBay as if they were glued together, so 4 categories instead of 5. But, my professor got 165,888 on the answer key. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2):

You have totally 5 categories, and you can think it like 5 seats, where Amazon and ebay must sit togather. So they can sit at "#1,#2", "#2,#3", "#3,#4" and "#4,#5", totally four cases, and for each case, Amazon and ebay can switch their seats. Within Amazon and within ebay, you have permutations for each group, so we get

$$4\cdot 2\cdot 4!\cdot 3!\cdot X$$

Next, let's figure out $X$. Note that you have done two seats for Amazon and ebay. The remaining three seats are for Wiki, Univ and google, so you have $3!$. Inside each group, you also have permutations $(4!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!)$, so we have

$$X=3!\cdot (4!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!)$$

So totally you have:

$$4\cdot 2\cdot 4!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!\cdot (4!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!)=1990656$$